# Meteor oauth package relogin

Tags: meteor

I am using the following packages with meteor

```
oauth
twitter
accounts-base
```

I am able register the user with `Twitter.requestCredential` to get the token and set it into my user account.services.. .

## QUESTION:

I can see the user is already logged in into his twitter account. 
How to i login the same user, into my site for a user who has already registered into my site with `Twitter.requestCredential` ?

Comment: Why not just use the `accounts-twitter` package?

Comment: Working, Do i still have to ask for permissions to authorize the app, is it the normal behavior? or user should get logged in automatically(if the user is logged into twitter) without ask permissions on the working site ?

Comment: and how to check if i am loggedin and connected to social site ? Is there any api/docs ? i couldn't find much on docs.meteor.org